# Storing value for a point using named tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

I am trying to design a spreadsheet app. I have been able to come up with a class for my Index which is typically the point consisting of row, col. I want to be able to assign a value to the point. The challenge is I am unable to update the value for that cell.

This is what I tried so far
**models.py**

```
class Index(NamedTuple):
    row: int
    """The row (y-coordinate)"""
    col: int
    """The column (x-coordinate)"""
    val: str = None
    @property
    def column_label(self):
        nreps = (self.col // 26) + 1
        char = chr(ord("A") + self.col % 26)
        return nreps * char

    @property
    def row_label(self):
        return str(self.row + 1)

     def __str__(self):
        if self.val:
             return f"{self.val}"
        return f"{self.column_label}{self.row_label}"

app.py
 class App:
    def set(self, index, raw):
     """index (Index): the cell to update
        raw (str): the raw string
    """
    
       index._replace(val=raw)
```

Tried the above, but the value for that cell even after assigning it in the set() is still None. What is the best approach to assign a value for that index ?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but cant you just do

```
index.val = raw
```

instead of

```
index._replace(val=raw)
```

Again, I am not sure if I understand correctly but is a working example with just your index class:

```
class Index():
    row: int
    """The row (y-coordinate)"""
    col: int
    """The column (x-coordinate)"""
    val: str = None
    @property
    def column_label(self):
        nreps = (self.col // 26) + 1
        char = chr(ord("A") + self.col % 26)
        return nreps * char

    @property
    def row_label(self):
        return str(self.row + 1)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.val:
             return f"{self.val}"
        return f"{self.column_label}{self.row_label}"

d = Index()

d.val = 2

print(d.val)

d.val = 100

print(d.val)
```

### output

```
2
100
```

Comment: Getting the following error when I do the above. I am trying to read from a csv file and create the index object and set values.

Comment: def read_csv(fname, sheet):
    with open(fname) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row, values in enumerate(reader):
            for col, value in enumerate(values):
                app.set(models.Index(row, col), value)
error - Traceback
app.set(models.Index(row, col), value)
   index.val = raw
AttributeError: can't set attribute

Comment: It is difficult to help, when I don't have the full code. Do you have a git with the files or something?

Comment: Is there a way we can have a chat or smething ? It's a private repo. So, can't share it

Comment: how many files do you have? not sure what the best approach is